# How transient data does not persist in database

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

With JPA specification when we declare any type as @transient , It does not persist in database. Also when we decare any method annotated with @transient it does not participate in database operation.

How JPA actuly handle the operation with transient filed in PersistenceUnit ?

Comment: Handle WHAT operation?

Comment: As you've said yourself, `@transient` fields are never persisted by the JPA. Your application can use these fields at runtime for its needs but every time a new instance of an object with `@transient` property is created, these `@transient` properties are empty. It is up to your application to control what and when is stored and accessed from these fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In persistence state the managed entities of persistence context synchronize with database. In  persistence context the fields of entities annotated with @transient behave as ordinary variable ( behavior depends upon application) and JPA did not allow this property state to behave like mapped object property in transaction perform with entities within the persistence context. So transient fields are not participate in transaction.